# Try and catch statements not working as intended to catch strange error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, thread-safety

On the frontend I have a SPA which through an MS Graph API call retrieves email data and attachments. The attachments are in base64 and the user selects the email they want to select and then this data is then reuploaded to the database and also the files are uploaded to onedrive via MS Graph API again from an `List<IFormfile>`. I am coming across a strange issue that happens intermittently. Basically the supporting documents are not uploaded to onedrive and my try catch does not seem to catch any errors to indicate why. When I step through the code sometimes it goes through and then other times it seems to cancel out in random spots. Could I be using task and async incorrectly?

```
private async Task UploadSupportingDocs(int ID, List<IFormFile> supportingDocs,
    string supportingDocsJSON)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Upload Supporting Docs");

    if (supportingDocs != null || supportingDocs.Count > 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<DocumentUploads> documents;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            //Use returned ID from previous query and save supporting documents
            var querySupport = "exec dbo.A2P_Edit_0136_RR_UploadSupportingDocs_QA"
                + " @supportingDocsJSON, @ID, @UserID";
            documents = connection.Query<DocumentUploads>(querySupport,
                new { supportingDocsJSON = supportingDocsJSON, ID = ID,
                UserID = UserID });
        }

        var tasks = documents.Select(async file => {
            try {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, file.DOCUMENT_PATH);
                    var fileName = file.DOCUMENT_FILENAME;
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
                    var supportingDoc = supportingDocs.Where(item => item.FileName
                        .Equals(file.FILENAME_AT_UPLOAD,
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await supportingDoc.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;

                            var UploadResponse = await oneDrive
                                .UploadFileStreamAsync(SharedDriveID,
                                memoryStream, fullPath, "replace");
                            var SharedLinkResponse = await oneDrive
                                .DriveItemLinksAsync(SharedDriveID, fullPath,
                                "path", "users", "edit");
                            connection.Query("exec dbo.SomeQuery @TAB_ID,
                                @DriveItemID, @WebURL, @EditLink", new
                            {
                                TAB_ID = file.TAB_ID,
                                DriveItemID = UploadResponse.Id,
                                WebURL = UploadResponse.WebUrl,
                                EditLink = SharedLinkResponse.Link.WebUrl,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File Upload Error: {ex}");
                }
        });

        Console.WriteLine($"Upload Supporting Docs Complete");
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Just to understand what is going on a bit more . On the front end we also send some JSON data with the file name so we can save it in our database in one swoop. Then in my async linq query it takes the filename that was uploaded and finds the associated `supportingDoc` in the `List<IFormFile>` to then upload it to onedrive and then save some additional stuff to the database like the generated id and such. It makes no sense why this would work sometimes then fail others even with the same documents. The files are also given a new unique name from the database call which is fullPath for the onedrive function. That function is also given below:

```
public async Task<DriveItem> UploadFileStreamAsync(string DriveID,
    MemoryStream SourceFile, string DestinationPath, string ConflictChoice)
{

    var tries = 0;
    var maxRetries = 1;

    DriveItem response = null;

    while (tries <= maxRetries)
    {
        tries++;
        try
        {
            using var stream = SourceFile;

            // Use properties to specify the conflict behavior
            // in this case, replace
            var uploadProps = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", ConflictChoice}
                }
            };

            // Create the upload session
            // itemPath does not need to be a path to an existing item
            var uploadSession = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                .ItemWithPath(DestinationPath)
                .CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();

            // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
            int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
            var fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(
                uploadSession, stream, maxSliceSize);

            var totalLength = stream.Length;
            // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
            IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => {
                Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {totalLength} bytes");
            });

            // Upload the file
            var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

            if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
            {
                response = uploadResult.ItemResponse;
                Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ?
                    $"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}" :
                    "Upload failed");
            }

            tries = maxRetries + 1;
        }
        catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains(
            "Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters
                    .GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(initialScopes, claimChallenge);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
            }
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Overall I am confused how the code would not work yet I am catching no errors.

The onedrive variable is defined in program.cs as:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOneDrive, OneDrive>();
```

And using dependency injection it is initiated in a `BaseController` class as follows:

```
// GET: HomeController
protected string connectionString;
protected string fileDirectory;
protected string UserID;
protected string locationOfLibreOfficeSoffice;
protected readonly IFileProvider _fileProvider;
protected readonly IOneDrive oneDrive;
protected readonly IEmailService emailService;
protected readonly string SharedDriveID;
protected readonly IEnumerable<string> initialScopes;
protected readonly string SignedOutRedirectUri;

public BaseController(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env,
    IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IOneDrive OneDrive, IEmailService EmailService)
{
    connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DBContext"];
    fileDirectory = "/files";
    UserID = accessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("UserID");
    oneDrive = OneDrive;
    emailService = EmailService;
    SharedDriveID = configuration["AzureAd:SharedDriveID"];
    initialScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
    SignedOutRedirectUri = configuration["AzureAd:SignedOutRedirectUri"];
}
```

Comment: What is your `oneDrive` variable which seems shared between all your tasks? If it is actually shared between the tasks, is it thread safe? If it is shared and not thread safe, no wonder you have random failures.

Comment: I use dependency injection to initiate it. I added it above for completeness

Comment: I reuse that oneDrive variable through all my controllers so I would be curious what would make it thread safe. Do I need to implement it as a Singleton?

Comment: How do you know that it's failing? You are not getting an exception, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your `oneDrive` variable is very likely an instance of a class which is not threadsafe.

And it is shared between all your tasks, that your code runs in parallel. So you have thread concurrency issues, and there are little options to fix it:

1. Do not run multiple threads in parallel sharing that variable.
2. Or cease using `oneDrive` as an injected dependency but instantiate one for each task, like you are already doing with the sql connection.
3. Or attempt to make that dependency threadsafe.

The last proposition is a lot harder than the two previous. And that is usually a bad idea to run many tasks in parallel for answering a single request to a Web application: that depletes the threads pool and prevents scaling up.

So, better change your code to cease running your tasks in parallel.

Just iterate over your collection with a `foreach`, awaiting what has to be awaited. Do not build a list of tasks that end up running in parallel.

Switching your dependency to a singleton as you ask in a comment will worsen the trouble: it would then be shared between concurrent requests to your SPA, causing even more thread concurrency troubles, when more than one user is using your application.

By the way, it seems you use synchronous database queries, connection openings, ... Better switch to async ones.

Comment: So from some reading the azure sdk functions are thread safe but can the parent class that I created OneDrive cause thread issues even if it uses thread safe methods? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/thread-safety

Comment: Yes, it can have thread concurrency issues, if it has any member mutated by the methods you are invoking.

Comment: I have added another way to avoid the thread concurrency issue, if that is the culkrpit. Can you ascertain this by rewriting your code according to my proposition 1 or 2?

Comment: Yea I will try 2 tomorrow and see if that helps!

Comment: Just curious though since you said this is bad practice. If the user uploads 10 documents and this approach opens ten tasks then wouldn’t I run out of threads? If so what happens?

Comment: Running out of threads means additional tasks are waiting for free threads. Incoming http requests are put in a waiting queue and may end up timed-out. So depending on your load, it may have no consequences, or it may have some.

Comment: So it turns out there was a data issue and my SQL guys fixed it. The results of documents was empty sometimes explaining the sporadic behavior. I am curious though because I do want to ensure thread safety even if its working consistently now. To convert OneDrive to an object I can use in a Using statement do I need to remove the services.transient<> line in my program.cs and then just add a using statement in my controller for the OneDrive service directly which is extended by OneDrive class in that cs file?

Comment: Likely your OneDrive dependency is actually threadsafe then, and you could then even set it up as a singleton instead. For using it directly instead as a dependency, I do not know, that is specific to each class, it depends on its own dependencies, ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code here, and lots of exception handling at different levels that stops the propagation of exceptions. I will draw your attention to just a single potential point of failure:

```
IEnumerable<DocumentUploads> documents;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //...
    documents = connection.Query<DocumentUploads>(/* ... */);
}

var tasks = documents.Select(async file => { /* ... */ });
```

When the `documents` sequence is enumerated, the underlying `connection` has already been disposed. So, unless the `connection.Query` method returns an already materialized collection, I would expect here an exception to occur.  To fix this, either defer the disposal of the `connection` until the `documents` have been fully enumerated, or materialize the sequence before exiting the `using` block:

```
DocumentUploads[] documents;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //...
    documents = connection.Query<DocumentUploads>(/* ... */).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Since documents is declared outside of using it should be maintained and usable.

Comment: @IrishRedneck [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MEvc28) is a demo, showing that variables declared outside a `using` might be unusable after the `using`.

Comment: I step through my code and that variable is when declared outside of using does stay in memory. I am assuming this is because Query() returns a primitive data type whereas your example is a reference to the object that is destroyed?